# how to view normal video in cardboard like youtube

Tags: android, youtube, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I have an app that plays normal and `VR` videos. My app has two players to play both types. In my `VrVideoView` there is a button that makes video play in **stereo mode**.

My question is: how can I view normal videos in `Cardboard` just like the `YouTube` app?

Comment: check this link and download one of the players and view normal video in Cardboard.  https://www.quora.com/Can-you-play-any-video-you-want-on-Google-cardboard

Comment: have you checked the new SDK: https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/video360